# autohotkey: what does local followed by a variable name mean in function?

Tags: function, variables, local, autohotkey

I've got an auto hotkey function:

```
loadkeyboard(ALanguage)
{
local i
k:=1
loop{
if k=512
break
a:=GetBits(k)
IniRead letter%a%,Keyboards.ini,%ALanguage%,%a%
if letter%a%=ERROR
letter%a%=
else
if(letter%a%="space")
letter%a%:=" "
k:=k+1
}
return true
}
```

in this function, what does local i mean? because i is not getting used anyware, and I think that in functions, all variables are by default local, so, what's the use of this line? I tried removing this line, and after removing / commenting, function stopped working. and I've changed the variable name after local keyword, but it worked good, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By declaring a local variable on the first line of a function you are putting the function in to Assume-global mode

This makes all other Variables then "i" global so that there value can be used or set outside of your function.

So in a way you can replace "local i" with global and get the same result.

Comment: Ok, I'll check by doing that, then will be back

Comment: Ya, thanks for answering, it worked fine, and now concept is also clear to me